# htaccess ssl redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, ssl

I am trying to do ssl redirection for few pages only e.g. viewcart, checkout and when I try to apply this rule it gives me server 500 error.

Below is the lines I am using in my htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [s=2]
RewriteRule ^viewcart$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/viewcart [R,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/checkout [R,L]
```

Thanks for help in advance. hope to get it resolved soon.

Thanks
mr p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` is not a valid flag for the [RewriteCond directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond)

> RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on [s=2]

You can achieve the same with below

```
#if not already https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^viewcart$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/viewcart [R,L]

#if not already https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^checkout$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/checkout [R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks that is what I am doing but thought of some better solution - but you pointed out "s is not valid flag .... " is the mistake I was doing ... Thanks